# Passing state between view models

Tags: oop, mvvm, dependency-injection, domain-driven-design

Just wondering really if there's a consensus on the 'right' way to do this, for MVVM, DDD, and other philosophies . . .

So I've got a login screen, represented by a ViewModel, LoginViewModel.  It can take a name and password.  It also takes in through dependency injection a LoginService, that implements the logic of taking the username and password, and retrieving the Employee object.

My question is what's the 'right' way to get this information to the next view model?  Let's say it's AccountSettings, which needs to know about the logged in employee.  How do we encapsulate that?  I've got an AccountSettingsViewModel, but should it require

a) An instance of the LoginViewModel?
b) An instance of the LoginService, which keeps a reference to the logged in employee
c) A shared object or field on a global object, like App or something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just an update here - wound up doing this so the services have dependencies on each other, but the ViewModels do not.

So, in the example above, AccountSettingsViewModel has a dependency on a AccountService.  AccountService has a dependency on LoginService (which holds the login state).  Not perfect, but seems to work OK.

Answer (score 2):

Personally all my view models in DDD or otherwise are simple data containers, used to restrict the data that gets sent from the application to the UI/view. I might include some code in my view models that's specific to transforming data for that view.  I also consider my view models to be coupled to my views (I only mention this because I've seen 2 teams put them in their own separate project/assembly away from the views!).

If I have anything copying data, or performing actions to get the data needed for the view model, this would live in either my domain model or my application layer, probably in a service.  I wouldn't ever inject a service into a view model.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  

I'm passing services actually to keep all logic out of VMs - I also want to avoid passing repositories directly to the VM, so the service is a way to abstract out coordination between entities.  

I guess 'service' in my example is being pretty open - but I'm trying also to avoid having silly objects that can't act as either Entities or ValueObjects, stuff like "LoginAccountEmployerCoordinator", that works between multiple entities to respond to view events.  There's also an event sourced model on many, so maybe that's what's complicating this.

Comment: Ideally I'd think your VMs SHOULD be decoupled from your views - the View should have a dependency on the ViewModel, but never the other way around.  This enables a single view model to support multiple platforms - for example, native mobile for tablet, phone, and also HTML pages.

Comment: Actually the worst things I've seen done with view models is when people spot commonality in repeating properties and try to make a complex hierarchy of inheritance.  I like to keep my view models and message objects very flat.  I've also seen people try to reuse a view model across views, because they happen to have the same properties in an attempt to appease the DRY gods, but not spotting that the views are different and only take the same properties by chance, chances are they will evolve separately over time in the future.

Comment: Hmmm  - in the case where it's different versions (platforms) presenting the same application, it would seem you'd want to reuse ViewModels.  Are you saying you'd have one ViewModel for Android, one for iOS, etc?

Comment: Interesting I guess in that case maybe you could share them, if you're replicating the exact same views for each mobile OS.